# On Mac OS X 10.8.3 I cannot print single sided to my Canon iR C2880

Tags: macos, printing, duplex, printing-software

I have installed the drivers here http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/support/office/color_imagerunner_copiers/color_imagerunner_c2550_c2880_c2880i_c3080_c3080i_c3380_c3380i_c3480_3480i for my C2880 and It doesn't give me the option for duplex printing like the installation manual shows. I have no idea what I am missing and I've been googling for a couple hours :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure about the specifics of your model, but for me the single/double sided options have been disabled on the Layout options and moved to the Finishing options areas on the print dialog.

Comment: You are correct, and I finally found it a few days later :)